# Error "Too many open files" in pdflatex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

When compiling a latex document with 15 or so packages and about five includes, pdflatex throws a "too many open files"-error. All includes are ended with \endinput. Any ideas what might cause the error?

The error seems to depend on how many packages are used (no surprise...); however, this is not the first time I use this many packages, while I've never encountered such an error before.

@axel_c: This is *not* about linux. As you may or may not know, LaTeX is also available on windows (which just happens to be what I'm using right now).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try inserting

```
\let\mypdfximage\pdfximage
\def\pdfximage{\immediate\mypdfximage}
```

before `\documentclass`.

See also these threads from the pdftex mailing list:

- [Error message: Too many open files.](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2008-March/007559.html)
- [Too many files open](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2009-October/008105.html)

Answer (score 3):

Type

```
ulimit -n
```

to get the maximum number of open files. To change it to e.g. 2048, type

```
ulimit -S -n 2048
```

Answer (score 1):

What is this command giving you:

```
$ ulimit -n
```

You might want to increase it by editing **/etc/security/limits.conf** file.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a low value in your 'max open file descriptors' kernel configuration. Assuming you're using Linux, you can run this command to find out current limit:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

If the limit is low (say, 1024 or so, which is the default in some Linux distros), you could try raising it by editing /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
  fs.file-max = 65536
```

Details may differ depending on your Linux distribution, but a quick google search will let you fix it easily.